# Why java -Xss doesn't work?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jvm, limits

I have an old and special Linux version:

> Linux version 2.4.32, gcc vercion 2.95.4

with an old JDK (version 1.6.0_13), and a simple program:

```
package threadtest;

/**
 * tim
 * 01.10.2014.
 */
public class ThreadCounter {
    private static class SleepRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                System.err.println("Thread started: " + i);
                new Thread(new SleepRunnable()).start();
            }
            Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

When I start the program (`-server -Xms256M -Xmx256M -XX:MaxPermSize=64M -Xss#k`), option -Xss doesn't matter (`-Xss64k or -Xss2G`). It seems that the stack size is always 2m.

ulimits -s -> unlimited
in /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
*   soft    nproc   65535
*   hard    nproc   65535
*   soft    nofile  65535
*   hard    nofile  65535
*   soft    stack   320
*   hard    stack   320
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you determining what the stack size of your Java process is?

Comment: The ulimit `stack` settings are not relevant.  They only relate to the JVM processes stack segment.  Java thread stacks are allocated in the data segment.

Comment: Maybe `k` or `G` aren't valid extensions for sizes for the `-X` options? Try `-Xss16m`

Comment: Thread stack size ~ (2G - Heap size - Permgen size - misc) / Number of threads.

Comment: I tried all variants,  among other things -XX:ThreadStackSize (it's doesn't work).

Comment: @StephenC Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @jameslarge - If I thought so, I would have done that.  IMO, it doesn't solve the OP's problem.  However, unless the OP responds to Peter's comment, I don't think we can help him.